# Products is undefined Laravel

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I'm getting this error `Undefined variable: $productsTR` while I have set the products variable in controller, I have a main blade and a partial blade. Main blade is the one that sends data to controller then returns to partial blade. How can I fix this `Undefined variable: $productsTR`?

HomeController

```
  public function viewProduct($id){
    $productsTR = Product::with('ProductsPhoto')->where('id',$id)->get();
    $returnHTML = view('productdetail')->with('productsTR', $productsTR)->render();
    return response()->json(array('success' => true, 'html'=>$returnHTML));
}
```

Route

```
Route::get('view-product/{id}', 'HomeController@viewProduct')->name('view.producT');
```

Partial Blade(productdetail)

```
@foreach($productsTR as $product)
@foreach($product->ProductsPhoto as $productImage)
           <img src="{{ Storage::url($productImage->filename) }}"  alt="small">
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Main blade

```
<div class="modal fade" id="view-product" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- 
labelledby="myModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    @include('productdetail')
</div>
</div>


 @foreach($products as $product)
    @if(count($product->ProductsPhoto))
    <a href="javascript:;" id="{{$product->id}}" class="modal-global" >
    <img src="{{Storage::url($product->ProductsPhoto[0]->filename)}}" alt="" >
</a>
        @endif
    @endforeach
```

Javascript

```
 <script>
$('.modal-global').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var product_id = $(this).attr("id");
var url = '{{route('view.producT',[":product_id"])}}';
url = url.replace(':product_id', product_id);

    $("#view-product").modal('show');

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'html',
    })
    .done(function(response) {
        $("#view-product").find('.view-product').html(response);
    });

});
</script>
```

Main blade (ProductController)

```
   public function index(Request $request)
  {
    $userId = $request->user()->id;
    $products = product::where('user_id', $userId)->paginate(20);
   return view('product.index',compact('products'));
   }
```

Main blade Route

```
Route::get('/user/product', 'ProductController@index');
```

Comment: Post the route and controller for displaying main blade.

Comment: Please check the updated question @JaseelPV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method 1**

The issue is you are not passing $productsTR in index function.

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $userId = $request->user()->id;
    $products = product::where('user_id', $userId)->paginate(20);
    
    $productsTR = NULL;//Add this line
    return view('product.index',compact('products', 'productsTR')); //update here
}
```

Then do a check here

```
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
  @if($productsTR)
    @include('productdetail')
  @else
    //add as per your needs or remove else part
  @endif
</div>
```

**Method 2**

Or if you only want to render through script, do like this

```
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
   <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body" id="renderedView">
        
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

$.ajax({
   type:'GET',
   url:url,
   dataType:'JSON,
   success:function(response){
       $("#renderedView").html(response.html);
   }
});
```

You can skip the 1st method if you are rendering only through ajax

Comment: That doesn't show any error but the thing is it only shows data on console but not in blade view I don't know why? that modal popup doesn't pop after click. @Jaseel P V

Comment: Actually you are included the file directly in main blade and what you are doing in ajax is appending the rendered view in #view-product. so i think you dont need to include the file in main blade directly

Comment: So I have to remove `@include('productdetail')` and add it where? @Jaseel P V

Comment: I don't know what is happening but the modal pops up with no data @Jaseel P V

Comment: check this line success:function(response){, i have given data instead of response, if you copied the same code please change and check

Comment: It shows this `{success: true,…}
html: "<h1>products</h1>↵↵<div>↵<img src="/storage/photos/mHcRKbcvrcBtwM1cMHEfV6hSI6cRFs2oHG3IXhcC.jpeg"alt="small">↵      </div>↵↵"
success: true` @Jaseel P V

Answer (score 1):

You have included the `productdetail` blade in your main blade at first load but you are not passing any data that's why the error come's up.

```
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    @include('productdetail')
</div>
```

Maybe you can put first a condition to check if `producsTr` is already set or not which in your case you are giving data only when the `#view-product` element is triggered.

Comment: I have tried to put if statement before `@include('productdetail')`  but that throws an error from the if statement  `undefined productsTR` @roberto albelda

Comment: what is your condition ? maybe you should put your condition inside your productdetail blade.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is when you pass data in blade file. you need to pass in array as below.

```
$returnHTML = view('productdetail',['productsTR'=>$productsTR])->render();
```

Comment: I'm still getting the undefined `productsTR` @Dilip Hirapara